# Creating a link to a page with pageid doesn’t work for MVC with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using jQuery Mobile with MVC. I don’t know how to create a link to Index page of a car controller with pageid.
I have two pages defined in _Layout.cshtml:
First page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="CarID">
<div data-role="header">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="@Url.Content("~/Car/Index/#CarID")">1. Page Car</a></li>
     <li><a href="@Url.Content("~/Car/Index/#MaintID")">2. Page Maint</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
   @RenderSection("PageCar")
```

Second page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="MaintID">
<div data-role="header">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="@Url.Content("~/Car/Index/#CarID")" >1. Page Car</a></li> 
      <li><a href="@Url.Content("~/Car/Index/#MaintID")">2. Page Maint</a></li> 
   </ul>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
   @RenderSection("PageMaint")
```

The problem is that these links render section in Index page in home controller NOT the index page in car controller. Links without page id work so href="@Url.Content("~/Car/Index") works but, obviously since no page id I don’t know how to get to a particular page ID. I tried all kind of links, none will not quite work or will take me to home controller Index view:

```
<li><a href="#MainID")">2 Page Maint</a></li>
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Car", new { id ="MaintID" })">2 Page Maint</a></li> 
<li>@Html.ActionLink("2 Page Maint", "Index", "Car", new { id = "Maint" }) </li>
```

Can somebody help to create a link to Index page of car controller with pageid? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks